# Java Event Processing Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm looking for a lightweight framework that builds on top of the Process Manager pattern:

http://www.eaipatterns.com/ProcessManager.html

I'm specifically interested in using this for doing event processing whereby I'm interested in the success or failure outcome of a particular event and passing a message on to another "stage" based on this outcome.  There may be other outcomes aside from success and failure, so I want something that's a little flexible...

I'm not really looking for a heavyweight ESB to handle this sort of situation since it seems like complete overkill.  Spring integration looks ok for this sort of thing.  Can anybody recommend any other frameworks to help achieve this?

The alternative is to build something using the basic Spring framework...

Answer (score 4):

The [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) project implements the patterns from the EIP book. I think it does exactly what you need.

Camel can be used with Spring and can be deployed in several different containers, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Hi Ken, I'm familiar with the Apache Camel framework, I'm curious as to why do you think it fits my needs better than Spring Integration though?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to say that Camel is better than Spring Integration, I'm not at all familiar with that product. What I meant to say is that Camel is a very direct implementation of the EIP patterns, so if that's what you are looking for then that framework will give you what you need. ProcessManager is kind of a generic pattern though, so you probably need to combine other EIP patterns to get what you want.

It looks like Spring Integration is in incubator (is that same as beta?) whereas Camel has reached v2.0.0, if that matters to you.

Comment: This article ("Integration Framework Comparison - Spring Integration, Mule ESB or Apache Camel") makes some good points as to why Camel is very likely a little bit more powerful than Spring Integration. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/03/integration-framework-comparison-spring.html#ixzz1qLZGq6j9 I am not a framework bigot (or try not to be) but I think the author's arguments are solid.